# How do I add footer widgets to the StudioPress Monochrome Pro theme?

Tags: widgets, footer, genesis-theme-framework

I spent all day creating a custom theme based on the Monochrome Pro Genesis child theme. But, I just noticed it doesn't have any footer widgets areas in Appearance > Widgets. I looked at the theme documentation and it doesn't have footer widgets areas! I looked in funtions.php and the code is there for widget support..

```
//* Add support for 4-column footer widgets.
add_theme_support( 'genesis-footer-widgets', 4 );
```

There are no remove_actions for the footer widgets. So, it seems like I should have widget areas.

I looked at another Genesis theme that has widget areas and the code is similar, it has the same line to add theme support, but nothing else that I can see.

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to get the footer widget areas to show? I can always register new widget areas, but I believe Genesis can do this without me adding unnecessary code.

Can anyone help? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Sorry, there were remove actions. I did a search, but must have searched on `genesis_footer_widgets` instead of `genesis_footer`.